# Whats the difference between the following queries? Getting the top 3 salaries for different department

Tags: mysql, join

I am practicing SQL and came across this issue. I am trying to find the top 3 salaries for each department. The table structure is basic with one employee table with columns (`Id`,`name`,`Salary`,`DepartmentId`) and a department Table with columns (`ID`,`DepartmentName`). In one query I use a join on the `departmentId` column, but this query takes longer than when I don't use a join and simply use two table as stated in the second query. My understanding was both are one and the same thing. Please shed some light about the difference between these two queries. What makes one faster than the other?

```
SELECT d.name as Department, e.name as Employee ,e.salary as Salary 
FROM Employee e , Department d 
where e.DepartmentId=d.Id and
    (SELECT COUNT(distinct Salary) 
     FROM Employee 
     WHERE Salary > e.Salary 
     AND DepartmentId=e.DepartmentId) < 3
```

The above query works well but when I write it in the similar way it takes long time.

```
SELECT d.name as Department, e.name as Employee ,e.salary as Salary
FROM Employee e 
JOIN Department d 
ON e.DepartmentId=d.Id 
AND
(SELECT COUNT(distinct Salary) 
 FROM Employee
 WHERE Salary > e.Salary 
 AND DepartmentId=e.DepartmentId) < 3
```

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) to get execution plans for both queries, then compare them and add them to the question. And add MySQL version too, please.

Comment: How much time does each query takes to run?

Comment: See the "Top-N" section of http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max .